# How to create a custom chart with Appcelerator Titanium (Alloy) for Android

Tags: titanium

How I create a custom chart like this

[image: image description here]

with Titanium's Alloy elements (xml, tss, js - no SVG or canvas)? Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have any good reason to avoid a webview? I don't like webviews either but for one think like a charts sometimes it's the best solution.

Comment: Yes, because I have difficult to edit an SVG or Canvas (for example one of these ones http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html). Is more simple edit and customize a file XML or JS to have  a custom chart

Comment: To draw a chart like the one you linked I used Google Charts in a webview passing data in json.

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach which worked for me was the using of a **webview** and **Google Charts**.

I stored my "skeleton html page" as local asset, and inside it I wrote the minimum necessary javascript to get the json (from the controller) and to draw the chart.
I didn't need to show data offline so I directly linked the online library but I'm almost sure it's possible to use it offline too.

https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is possible to color the "background" of columns like this image? http://it.tinypic.com/r/rbllar/9
I don't find the solution in the API

Comment: There are a lot of configurations but I don't think you can change background colors of only some columns: 
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options
By the way there are a lot of js libraries you can use, using a webview you don't have limits.